# How can I stop default submission of form using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: forms, addeventlistener

I would like to stop default submission using Vanilla JavaScript. I created a sample of little form. But it gets refreshed when I submit the form even though I call the `preventDefault()` method. When I use `input type="button"` it works. But not works with `input type="submit"`.

What will be the reason? Can anyone explain me what is the right method and what's wrong with the code?

My code is as follows:

```js
let validation = () => {
  let form = document.querySelector(".form");
  form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Optional Help: Can anyone give me a proper method or any good references on creating forms. Because when I search, I got lots of tutorials where all are says different methods and I really struggle to find out which method is the standard one.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following changes to your code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" class="form" method="post" onsubmit="validation(event)">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Try removing the return keyword and add event parameter.

**JavaScript**

```
const validation = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

Using the `preventDefault()` method of event, the form is hopefully not submitted! Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Hi Adam, your code is working only without wrapping in the function. But when i wrap your code with validation function, it not works. Can you give me an idea on what went wrong with it. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Hello and Merry Christmas! I’m sorry, I didn't realize that your code was in the ```validation()``` function. I will update the code and add some explanation too.